# Desabilitar o agendamento de eventos pelo mes fullcalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

Tenho um programa e tem como agendar os eventos pelo mês e pela semana, estou utilizando o fullcalendar jQuery, gostaria de desabilitar o agendamento de eventos pelo mês. E agendar só pela semana.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar somente a semana, pode fazer duas coisas:

1º - Coloque na inicialização

> defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

isso fará com que o calendário inicialize no modo agenda.

2º - Remova botão 'month' do header

```
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
```

Se quiser ainda desabilitar os eventos 'allday', inicializando

> 'allDaySlot': false

Um exemplo pode ser visto no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustavoR/1kauckLq/10/)

Pode encontrar mais opções no [Fullcalendar Docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/)